# Amazon RDS: Oracle SQL Developer - Database Copy hanging?

Tags: oracle, cloud, amazon-rds

After creating a Oracle Instance on Amazon RDS I'm trying to import data by following the instructions here for Oracle SQL Developer - Database Copy:

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-RDS/4173109646282306

My DB size is approximately 50GBs. It was running fine and I could see the DDL progress, data migration, etc but now it seems like it's stuck on a table that has approximately 350k records.  My questions are:

1. For anyone that has tried DB Copy to Amazon RDS for Oracle, how big is your DB and how long did it take?
2. Is it safe to kill SQL Developer and restart the process?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check `v$session_longops` to see if there is still something going on.

Comment: it resumed again after 2 1/2 hours and also posting this same question on the aws developer forums.

Comment: Continued and then states 'Copying (Failed)' after 2:40:36 (h:mm:ss). There are no messages stating why and seems there is no way to view log files on RDS yet. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=412809